# System Services in Automator won't start

Tags: automator, services

For about a week it occurs that System Services created in Automator suddenly refuse to work.

It happens on all Services, system-wide, i.e.:

- *Open in Marked* in Byword
- *Create Symlink* in Finder
- *Subscribe To Comment Feed* in Chrome

I'm not able to reproduce it, the only solution right now is to restart my Mac. System Services will work for a certain time and suddenly they will stop working again.

It also doesn't depend on the trigger. Via menu, via shortcut or via iCal, everything fails.

No output in Console.App.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could try running "Disk Utility.app", manually, and try to do the following:

1. Repair permissions.
2. Verify or repair disk.

If that doesn't work, you could try to narrow it down by starting from another volume with a different copy of the System Software.

That's worth a try I think.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately repairing permissions and disks didn't help either. There was indeed a problem with my disk (orphanded blocks) but the problem with Automator Services still persists after solving the disk issues.